# Not able to access enum defined on an rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums

I have this enum defined on a model for implementing a wizard interface for my rails6 app

```rb
enum form_steps: {
        companyinfo: [:vendor_business_name, :vendor_web_site, :vendor_addr_line1, :vendor_addr_line2, :vendor_addr_city, :vendor_addr_zipcode, :vendor_addr_country],
        proprietorinfo: [:vendor_proprietor_fname, :vendor_proprietor_lname, :vendor_mobile_phone, :vendor_email, :vendor_ownership_type],
        complianceinfo: [:vendor_gstin_number, :vendor_registration_number, :vendor_bank_account_branch_name, :vendor_bank_account_ifsc_code, :vendor_bank_account_number, :vendor_bank_account_type]
    }
```

However when i try to access this enum on my rails console by calling `Vendor.form_steps` i get this error `` 'NoMethodError (undefined method `vendor_addr_country' for Vendor (call 'Vendor.connection' to establish a connection):Class)' ``

How can i get this resolved?

Comment: I have the corresponding migration up and have all the fields applied on my db schema

Comment: When you look at the [docs for `enum`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) then there is an example using a hash like you. But the description tells that the keys/value pairs define the enum value names and how they are stored in the database. In the documentation, there is no example using nested arrays, and given that the values define how the data is stored in the database nested arrays do not really make sense in this context. What do you try to achieve by the nested arrays and what documentation to you follow that describes a usecase like that?

Comment: What you're doing here is completely out of scope for `ActiveRecord::Enum`. Its just used to map a single integer column to a set of developer friendly labels to create an enumeration of finate states. An example of that is `{ draft: 0, in_review: 1, published: 2 }`. Creating steps and substeps with a single enum is not going to work.

Comment: You should probably go back to the drawing board and perhaps look at existing solutions like wicked and really reconsider jamming all this into a single column or even a single model.

Answer (score 0):

```
  enum form_steps: {
        companyinfo: [:vendor_business_name, :vendor_web_site, :vendor_addr_line1, :vendor_addr_line2, :vendor_addr_city, :vendor_addr_zipcode, :vendor_addr_country],
        proprietorinfo: [:vendor_proprietor_fname, :vendor_proprietor_lname, :vendor_mobile_phone, :vendor_email, :vendor_ownership_type],
        complianceinfo: [:vendor_gstin_number, :vendor_registration_number, :vendor_bank_account_branch_name, :vendor_bank_account_ifsc_code, :vendor_bank_account_number, :vendor_bank_account_type]
    }
```

when you add this in your model, try to restart the application
also try `spring stop` also check if your DB connection is really working

`Vendor.form_steps` should return :

```
{
       "companyinfo" => [
        [0] :vendor_business_name,
        [1] :vendor_web_site,
        [2] :vendor_addr_line1,
        [3] :vendor_addr_line2,
        [4] :vendor_addr_city,
        [5] :vendor_addr_zipcode,
        [6] :vendor_addr_country
    ],
    "proprietorinfo" => [
        [0] :vendor_proprietor_fname,
        [1] :vendor_proprietor_lname,
        [2] :vendor_mobile_phone,
        [3] :vendor_email,
        [4] :vendor_ownership_type
    ],
    "complianceinfo" => [
        [0] :vendor_gstin_number,
        [1] :vendor_registration_number,
        [2] :vendor_bank_account_branch_name,
        [3] :vendor_bank_account_ifsc_code,
        [4] :vendor_bank_account_number,
        [5] :vendor_bank_account_type
    ]
```

Thanks